# Created JWT and decoding/encoding within Mirth

Tags: java, jwt, mirth

I created a key on jwt.io and going through testing so after I get the generated encoded key and paste it on row 111 below, I get an error on line 113 for invalid key format.  My guess based on my limited knowledge is that I'm not passing in the right encoded key or there's an issue with my code.  Any assistance in pointing me to the right direction will be helpful!  Thanks.

Code below:

```
108: var keyFac = java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
109: enter code here`109: var privateKey;
110: 
111: encoded = Packages.org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64('<encoded output from jwt.io>');
112: keySpec = new Packages.java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
113: privateKey = keyFac.generatePrivate(keySpec);
114: 
115: claims.setGeneratedJwtId();
116: claims.setIssuer('');
117: claims.setSubject('');
LINE NUMBER:    113
DETAILS:    Wrapped java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
```

Comment: *I created a key on jwt.io* - jwt.io is a site on which you can test (and create) JWTs, but it's not a key generator. So it remains unclear what you actually did and where you created what kind of key.

Comment: That makes sense.  I'm fairly new to this.  I guess what I'm trying to figure out is for row 111 what gets passed through?

Comment: I'm not sure how to edit a comment but I was able to determine that I need to pass through a client id. Thank you.